# Google Index problem

Tags: google, problem

I forwarded my site to Google, because Google is not indexing my site. I do not understand why. My website has many backlinks from other sites.

What can I do?

Comment: It can take a while for a website to be indexed. Did you check [webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en&pli=1)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Google doesn't index your website might be the links. If the links are on websites that are not somehow related to your website, or the websites are just links to other websites, Google might have got rid of your website, because you're breaking Google SEO rules.

Have a look at http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34441 for more help.